# Can CSS be modified to scale contents of div to 100% of window?

Tags: css, scale

I'm currently building a site using this framework template: http://cargocollective.com/montessori

My goal is to make the thumbnails scale in size to fill 100% of the screen, just like this site: http://mariohugo.com (resize window to see this in action)

Does anyone know if this can be done by modifying the CSS in any way?

Answer (score 1):

That site is done with JavaScript - if you turn your JavaScript off, you get no images at all. Not very compatible!

You can do something similar with fluid CSS layouts, though it won't be quite as slick as that site.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm limited with the amount of modifications I can make with the Cargo template and was hoping I could get mod CSS or even add some HTML/js to make this effect possible.

Comment: Looks like it was based on a system by http://www.squarespace.com/ - check out the JS on http://mariohugo.com, maybe you can see how it is done and apply it to your own site

Answer (score 0):

have a look at twitter bootstrap framework http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. It might help you.